# macOS can't detect my Feitian MultiPass U2F Device over BLE

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

I'm enrolled in Google's Advanced Protection program, and it requires me to carry a physical U2F token when signing in through a new device. I've also started using this as my only second-factor authentication method.

My [Feitian MultiPass U2F key](https://www.ftsafe.com/Products/FIDO/Multi) device is BLE and can authenticate via Bluetooth. I had no problems pairing it with my phone, but when I tried pairing it with my MacBook, I couldn't even see it listed in the list of new devices.

At the same time, my MacBook can see my phone and had no trouble pairing with my headphones. I can use my U2F token with my phone just fine.

I also tried using it via Bluetooth with my wife's Macbook, and that didn't work either. The same problem, it didn't even show up.

Our laptops:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) running 10.13.5 High Sierra
- MacBook Pro (2016 with Touchbar) running 10.13.5 High Sierra

Comment: Have you contacted Google Support?  Given that its failing on two different laptops, there may be a compatibility issue.

Comment: @Allan It's a non-Google product by a company called Feitian. I suppose I should contact their support as well. I was just confused about how this was possible

Comment: @AminShahGilani, I also face the same issue. Would you have any update on this? Did you manage to somehow sort it out?

Comment: @AminShahGilani, here is more information on that issue:
I'm no expert on this, so may be wrong, but some googling shoes that BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) requires Bluetooth v4.0 at least. And apparently, this can be checked in a terminal with this command: system_profiler -detailLevel full SPBluetoothDataType | grep "LMP Version"

; In my case, this shoes: LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)
; I believe this mean that the issue is with the Feitian MultiPass?

Comment: Hi everyone,

I'm running into the exact same problem today. I don't have useful updates just a thought:

I guess this is one of the reasons why extended authentication requires 2 keys (a bluetooth enabled one and a USB one). Many ppl have Mac machines and they don't seem to work with the bluetooth key. However, phones are often not easily USB enabled (iPhone I'm looking at you).

I guess to keep it simple one uses USB for laptop and Bluetooth for phones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that they are not compatible with Macs via BLE.  Their site lacks this info and so does the amazon listing if you purchased there.  To top it even if you could connect your mac to the device the chrome browser is looking for a USB key.  This is pure garbage since all macs don't carry the same ports, I.E my mini is USB3, my pro is USB-C.  Returning and turning off Advanced protection.